# LaTeX in Word/Office 2011?

Tags: mac, msword

I remember I read somewhere out there that Office 2011 Word will support TeX (LaTeX).
Is this true? I have Office 2011 on my Mac but I cannot find anything related to TeX.

Comment: If I remember well, then the math typesetting is now done with the the same algorithms like TeX does it already.

Comment: It does not, as Joseph Wright, answered. However, I wrote this AppleScript for Word in Office 2011, which gives you a highly customizable way of converting DOC and DOCX to unicode LaTeX (XeLaTeX) if you make use of styles. See this AppleScript: [texifyWord](https://gist.github.com/macmadness86/5582426)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do have Office 2011: this is not true (with the exception that you can use Word to save plain text, of course). As Herbert has commented, the equation editor in recent versions of Office has been much improved, and uses a lot of ideas from TeX.

Comment: To be precise, Word's math typesetting is more advanced than TeX's one, and the enhancements are being ported back to LuaTeX.

Comment: Word is not as flexible as TeX. You cannot make things in Word like `\vskip 5pt plus 10pt minus 2pt` or cannot typeset the `\TeX` logo either.

Comment: @Adam: I was commenting specifically on the equation editor in recent Word versions, and in particular the additional fontdimens it understands (compared with the TeX set of math-related fontdimens).

Answer (score 1):

What may be meant is that the Word 2007/2011 Equation Editor [understands some TeX commands](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUrVUhcWLnQ#t=60s) (see 1:00).