# Is there a way to toggle LaTeX within MathType?

Tags: conversion, editors, mac

I understand that [in Word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41764/7844), there is a simple way to toggle MathType objects so that they can be displayed and edited as LaTeX. Is there a way to do this *within* MathType itself (e.g. for workflows that use other word processors, such as Pages)?

Comment: This is not about (La)TeX, it is about Word/MathType. Very likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: I'm not sure then were to ask it. Can you transfer to the right SE?

Comment: try superuser.com

Comment: Actually, I'd prefer to leave this here. This seems to be [the place](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8306/7844) to get an answer.

Comment: I know that if you have the most recent MathType you can input Latex code and get the output image. Go to Preferences>Workspace Preferences and select "Allow Tex language entry from keyboard."

Comment: @azetina: That looks like an answer! Is there a way to toggle back the other way, from rendered to LaTeX?

Comment: On the Mathtype main menu just click on "Toggle Tex" to go from image to tex and once more to regenerate the image.

Comment: @azetina: Where is that located. I don't see "Toggle Tex" among the menus.

Comment: I was going with: "(La)TeX related software and tools like BibTeX, LyX, LaTeX editors, viewers, and converters".

Comment: IMO, this question is not completely off-topic here and should not be closed.  Seems to me like a bit of a knee-jerk reaction to MS Word being mentioned.

Comment: @Tomek In my opinion this question falls outside the guidelines given in the faq. Involving Word is not the issue, as raxacoricofallapatorius pointed out such a question earlier (with not a single downvote). Rather, this question involves software emulating the output of LaTeX, and historically such questions have often been determined to be off topic. Mathjax is another common candidate for closures for this reason.

Comment: @Mark S. Everitt: the question is about using MathType as a LaTeX equation editor (from the user input point of view). In my mind that makes it relevant enough for this site and I don't see anything specific in the faq to the contrary, in particular, why emulating the output of LaTeX or not would have any bearing on the issue.

Comment: @Tomek: The issue of what is off topic is hazy around the boundary, and your points are of course valid. Nonetheless, I think this question is off topic, since there is no TeX processor involved and the "LaTeX" code here is a subset. You are welcome to open a question to debate this matter on the meta site if you still believe that this question is on topic. Closure is achieved through votes among those with sufficient reputation, as is reopening, so please keep in mind that this is not arbitrary.

Comment: @Tomek: I'd like to add that this is not a criticism of Word, MathType or MathJax, which I mentioned earlier (I make extensive use of MathJax in fact). We simply have to draw boundaries.

Comment: @Tomek: Perhaps this is worth discussing on [meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2176/7844), since the FAQ appear to be out of sync with this close decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can toggle in MathType between rendered output and the corresponding LaTeX code (MathType uses internally its own format rather than LaTeX to store the equation data), but you can choose LaTeX as a copy/paste format somewhere in the preferences.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have the latest version and on the Mathtype Tab (see image below) click on "Toggle Tex" to change from image to tex and tex to image. Ensure you have the image selected and vice-versa.

[image: Toggle Tex location]

Comment: I don't have Word.